# AngularJS: setting background color dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-style

I have this table showing software logs, which gets populated by JSON data:

```
<div ng-controller="LogCtrl">
  <table id="logtable" style="width:100%">
    <tr>    
        <th>Timestamp</th>
        <th>Severity</th>
        <th>Message</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="log in logs" class="logentry">
        <td>{{log.timestamp}}</td>
        <td>{{log.severity}}</td>
        <td>{{log.message}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It works fine, but I would like to be able to change each `tr` element background following its severity. For example, if the severity of that log is "ERROR", its entry in the table should have red background, if the severity is "MESSAGE", it should be green, etc.

I already took a look at `ng-style`, but I didn't find out how to use it for this purpose.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by `ng-class` conditional operator

```
<tr ng-repeat="log in logs" class="logentry" 
    ng-class="{ 'ERROR': 'severity-error', 'MESSAGE': 'severity-message'}[log.severity]">
    <td>{{log.timestamp}}</td>
    <td>{{log.severity}}</td>
    <td>{{log.message}}</td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
.severity-error {
    background-color: red;
}

.severity-message {
    backgroud-color: green;
}
```

Comment: To make it cleaner, a directive which accepts the log severity and switches the class would be a good design decision.

Answer (score 2):

Same as above, but with `ng-style`.

```html
<tr ng-repeat="log in logs"
    ng-style="{'ERROR':{background:'red'}, 'INFO':{background: 'green'}}[log.severity]">
    <td>{{log.timestamp}}</td>
    <td>{{log.severity}}</td>
    <td>{{log.message}}</td>
</tr>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('tableController', function($scope) {
  $scope.logs = [
    {
               timestamp: 'foo',
               severity: 'ERROR',
               message: 'Something bad happened'
    },
    {
               timestamp: 'bar',
               severity: 'INFO',
               message: 'This is ok'
    },
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>

<table ng-controller="tableController" ng-app="app">
 <tr ng-repeat="log in logs"
     ng-style="{'ERROR':{background:'red'}, 'INFO':{background: 'green'}}[log.severity]">
   <td>{{log.timestamp}}</td>
   <td>{{log.severity}}</td>
   <td>{{log.message}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```